# bookmarklet to get full path to an image

Tags: javascript, path, bookmarklet

I'm working on a bookmarklet that gives the full path to an image when you click on any image on a web page. The image is then downloaded on our servers, and we do business stuff to it.

Currently, the script parses out the `src` attribute using jQuery, then has some dumb logic that usually works, but quite often it does not.

Now, I could keep writing ugly code to do a better job of parsing out the url using regex and stuff, but I feel like there should be some better way of doing this.. Finding some way to mimic (as in firefox) "Right-Click => Copy Image Location" would be fantastic.

Here is the relevant js code I have currently (buggy, but it usually works).. Any innovative ideas on how to better accomplish this?

```
var imgsrc;
$("img").click(function() {
  imgsrc = $(this).attr("src");
  var url = document.URL;

  if (window.location.pathname != "/") {
    var pathLoc = url.indexOf(window.location.pathname);
    url = url.substr(0, pathLoc + 1);
  } else if (window.location.pathname.substr(0,1) == "/") {
    url = url.substr(0, url.length - 1);
  }

  if (imgsrc.toLowerCase().indexOf("http://") != 0) {
    imgsrc = url + imgsrc;
  }

  window.open("http://www.mycompany.com/whatever?imgsrc=" + imgsrc + "");
});

$("img").hover(function () {
  $(this).css({'border' : '4px solid #ff0000'});
  }, function () {$(this).css({'border' : ''});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe most browsers normalize the **`SRC`** property (I mean the DOM property, not **`getAttribute('src')`**). So you could try:

```
$("img").click(function() {
    window.open("http://www.mycompany.com/whatever?imgsrc=" + this.src + "");
});
```

If that doesn't work then I know for a fact that anchor tags have their **`HREF`** properties normalized; this will definitely work:

```
$("img").click(function() {
    var fullSrc = $('<a/>').attr('href', this.src)[0].href;
    window.open("http://www.mycompany.com/whatever?imgsrc=" + fullSrc + "");
});
```

Comment: the first one totally worked and totally killed 10 lines of bad code. Thanks!

Comment: actually, it's pretty important to escape your url.. now it works for everything:

$("img").click(function() {
    window.open("http://www.mycompany.com/whatever?imgsrc=" + escape(this.src) + "");
});

Comment: @fuhrysteve, yup, but you should be using encodeURIComponent()

Answer (score 0):

To add a menu to the contextual menu, you have to create an extension for firefox. I've created an extension for wikipedia [here](http://plindenbaum.blogspot.com/2008/02/creating-xul-extension-for.html): you might be interested by the code.